# How can i make dynamic pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-queries

I would like to make dynamic pl/sql using type variables in parameter values.

parameter value 
>
type = {'name + place', 'resno', 'hpno', 'telno'};

for example 
if i got parameter values('resno', 'hpno')
Two combine queries're required(2 union all) 
so, it means that The number of queries depends on the parameter value.

```
select * from (
--repeatation
select * from
(select a.custnm
     , 'name + place' as vtype
     , a.custnm || '-' || c.pjtcd || '-' || c.dong || '-' || c.ho as con
     , count(a.custid) as nodup 
from   custtable a
     , thng c 
where a.custid = c.custid(+)
group by a.custnm, c.pjtcd, c.dong, c.ho
having count(a.custid) > 1) x
--/repeatation
union all
--repeatation
select * from
(select a.custnm
     , 'resno' as vtype
     , a.resno as condup
     , count(a.custid) as nodup 
from   custtable a
group by a.custnm, a.resno
having count(a.custid) > 1) x2
--repeatation
union all
--repeatation
select * from
(select a.custnm
     , 'hpno' as vtype
     , a.hpno as condup
     , count(a.custid) as nodup 
from   custtable a
group by a.custnm, a.hpno
having count(a.custid) > 1) x3
--repeatation
union all
--repeatation
select * from
(select a.custnm
     , 'telno' as vtype
     , a.telno as condup
     , count(a.custid) as nodup 
from   custtable a
group by a.custnm, a.telno
having count(a.custid) > 1) x4
--repeatation
) 
order by decode(vtype, 'name +`enter code here` place', 1 ,'resno', 2 ,'hpno', 3,  'telno', 4), nodup desc
```

plz let me know how to make plsql with parameter value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `SELECT` statement. The way it is written now, it is SQL, not PL/SQL, and my suggestion is to **leave it that way**. Instead of writing a horrible PL/SQL (dynamic SQL usually isn't nice), why wouldn't you create a **view**, based on that statement?

```
create or replace view v_my_view as
select * from (
--repeatation
select * from
(select a.custnm
     , 'name + place' as vtype
<snip>
```

Once you do that, use it anywhere you want (PL/SQL included).